# How the input is provided in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am totally new to lisp, but I came accross this code https://github.com/wjur/sym-diff-lisp/blob/master/sym-diff.lsp which calculates derivatives in lisp and I wanted to know how to run it. I see the examples in comments in the beginning but I am not sure how to run it.
I just installed clisp in ubuntu and tried to run 'clisp sym-diff.lsp' but I dont know where am i supposed to pass the exact functions that I want to differentiate. Should I pass it as arguments when running sym-diff.lsp?

Comment: The book Practical Common Lisp is quite good and available [online](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/) at no cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start CLISP - you should have a terminal window, which is waiting for you to do something. This is your REPL.

[image]

You have to load the code, thus:

- (cd "*file-location*")
- (load "*filename*")

Once you done that then you can type in your examples into the REPL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
I tried to do that but I only get 'SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable CD has no value' or SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable LOAD has no value'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, I just forgot the ()

Comment: No need to `cd` first. Just do: `(load #P"/full/absolute/path/to/sym-diff.lsp")` in this case.